# Haskell - type classes

Tags: function, haskell, symbols, typeclass

I am new to Haskell, and am trying to learn how type classes work.
I typed the following code into my GHCi compiler.

```
let (+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a;
(+) a b = a+b;
```

The code compiles, but whenever I call the function, it stuck and I have to ctrl+c to stop the process.

Am I doing anything wrong here?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but it surely is a problem. But I have also tried `let (+++) :: Num a => a -> a -> a; (+++) a b = a+b` which did not work either. What seems to be the problem here.

Comment: Because you still have an infinite loop in your `+`, most likely. Did you restart the GHCi session?

Comment: Got you! yes that was the problem. I restarted GHCi and it worked! Since both answers are helpful, I am voting for who answered first. I appreciate both of your answers tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling your function `+` from your function `+` recursively, it's the same as if you wrote:

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add a b = add a b
```

Answer (score 8):

You've defined `a + b` to be equal to `a + b` (the `+` infix operator can also be written as `(+)`, in which case it behaves as an ordinary prefix function; but your left-hand-side is still the same thing as your right-hand-side).

So the interpreter is just spinning forever, as to evaluate `a + b` it then needs to evaluate `a + b`, which then requires an evaluation of `a + b`, and so on.